# How to manage filesystem folders in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, filesystems, project-structure, visual-c++-2015

I like my folder structure to reflect my C++ namespace structure (mainly to avoid filename collisions), and I like to view this structure in the solution explorer. The latter I accomplish by using the VC++ "filter" feature creating a filter for every folder (incl. nested filters for nested folders). However, maintaining such a setup implies duplicated effort every time I create or move a file/folder. Any way to see&manage my folder structure in the solution explorer directly, as I can in VC#?

Or, in case I'm having a case of a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), what better way is there to cleanly structure the project, avoiding all kinds of name collisions?

I've seen my approach used in at least one popular C++ project (LibCinder), but I wonder how they manage it without going crazy. :)

Comment: [CMake](https://cmake.org/) might be helpful. By default, it creates visual studio projects, using the filesystem to deduce the filter structure.

Comment: I had similar problem with one very old and big project. So I've created a python script that generates project file and filters. Here is the [link to github](https://github.com/Teivaz/vcxproj-generator)

Comment: @IInspectable, teivaz: Thanks. Both of these are fine for initially generating a project, but while I'm working on the project, I don't want to regenerate the project file and reopen the solution every time I manipulate the project structure from the filesystem.

Comment: The above comment goest to @teivaz, too.

Comment: The solution here would be to create a custom build step, that checks for changes and triggers generation of the project files. This would make the process automatic, so you don't have to do anything (except adding files to the file system).

Comment: @IInspectable: Well, I'd still need to close and reopen the solution, which takes a long time and discards undo-history. Also, I prefer managing the project structure from within the VS solution explorer (and not from Windows Explorer).

Comment: You don't have to reload the solution. Reloading the projects is required, but that is (semi-)automatic, and doesn't take all that long, even for larger projects (I'm using this approach with a solution containing ~100 projects). Besides, if you follow the suggestion above to have a custom build step check for file system changes, it doesn't matter how the changes are initiated. It'll work the same whether you use File Explorer, Visual Studio, any other file editor, or a tool.

Comment: @IInspectable: I just discovered a button in the solution explorer called show all files which seems awesome, seems to solve a lot of issues at once. It lets me work with and view the folder structure instead of the filter structure. It lets me e.g. create a folder directly in VS and move files to it, or even create a file/class directly in it. No need to bother with filters anymore. It's compatible with the git integration too. If nothing unforeseen happens, this is gonna be the answer to my question.